# Show that $F(t)$ is differentiable for $t > 0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

**Edit:**

I picked a bad function $g$ in my first try. In my second attempt (below), I am trying to rectify this by picking different functions $g$ based on the given interval.

**My Second Attempt:**

> Part 2 of the theorem below states that if a suitable function $g$ is found, then $F(t)$ is differentiable on $a \leq t \leq b$. Since we want to show differentiability for $t > 0$, the plan is to consider closed intervals that cover $(0, \infty)$ and select an appropriate function $g$ for each closed interval.\
>
> First consider intervals of the form $$I_m = \left[\frac{1}{m+1}, \frac{1}{m}\right]$$
>
> for $m \in \mathbb{N}$. This gives us intervals that will cover $(0, 1]$. For such an interval, define
>
> \begin{align*}
>     g_m(x) := \frac{xe^{-\frac{1}{m+1}x}}{1+x}.
> \end{align*}
>
> Then $$\frac{xe^{-tx}}{1 + x} \leq g_m(x)$$ for all $x \in [0, \infty)$ and $t \in I_m$.
>
> **Want to argue that**
>
> \begin{align*}
>     \int_{[0, \infty)} g_m(x) \, d\mu_{\mathcal{L}}(x) &= \int_{[0, \infty)} \frac{xe^{-\frac{1}{m+1}x}}{1+x} \, d\mu_{\mathcal{L}}(x)\\
>     &< \infty.
> \end{align*}
>
> **This seems reasonable based on results from some integral calculators.**\
>
> Next, consider intervals of the form $$J_n = [1, n]$$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. These intervals will cover the rest of $(0, \infty)$. For such an interval, define
>
> \begin{align*}
>     h_n(x) := \frac{xe^{-x}}{1+x}.
> \end{align*}
>
> Then $$\frac{xe^{-tx}}{1 + x} \leq h_n(x)$$ for all $x \in [0, \infty)$ and $t \in J_n$.
>
> **Want to argue that**
>
> \begin{align*}
>     \int_{[0, \infty)} h_n(x) \, d\mu_{\mathcal{L}}(x) &= \int_{[0, \infty)} \frac{xe^{-x}}{1+x} \, d\mu_{\mathcal{L}}(x)\\
>     &< \infty.
> \end{align*}

---

**Original post:**

I am unable to finish this proof. I will state the 1) the problem, 2) a relevant theorem, 3) my attempt, and then 4) some discussion and questions at the end.

**The Problem:**

> Show that $F(t) = \int_{[0, \infty)} \frac{e^{-tx}}{1+x}d\mu_{\mathcal L}(x)$ is differentiable for $t > 0$.

(We are integrating with respect to the Lebesgue measure.)

**A Relevant Theorem (part 2 in the picture):**

> [image]

**My attempt:**

> In order to show that the function $F(t)$ is differentiable for $t > 0$ we will try to show that part 2 of the theorem above applies to $F(t)$, because then that theorem will tell us that $F(t)$ is differentiable with respect to $t$, and in particular that
>
> \begin{align*}
>     \frac{d}{dt} \left[\int_{[0, \infty)} \frac{e^{-tx}}{1 + x} \, d\mu_{\mathcal{L}}(x)\right] = \int_{[0, \infty)} \frac{d}{dt} \left[\frac{e^{-tx}}{1 + x}\right] \, d\mu_{\mathcal{L}}(x).
> \end{align*}
>
> First, the theorem requires that the derivative with respect to $t$ of the function in the integrand of $F(t)$ exists for each $x \in [0, \infty)$. Since the integrand is a constant times the differentiable function $e^{-tx}$, we know that the derivative exists.\
>
> Second (and lastly), the theorem requires the existence of a non-negative measurable function $g$ with
>
> \begin{align*}
>     \int g \, d\mu_{\mathcal{L}}(x) &< \infty \text{ and}\\
>     \left| \frac{d}{dt} \left[\frac{e^{-tx}}{1 + x}\right] \right| &\leq g(x) \text{ for all } x \in [0, \infty) \text{ and } a \leq t \leq b.
> \end{align*}
>
> By standard rules of differentiation we have
>
> \begin{align*}
>     \frac{d}{dt} \left[\frac{e^{-tx}}{1 + x}\right] &= \frac{-xe^{-tx}}{1 + x}, \text{ so}\\
>     \implies \left| \frac{d}{dt} \left[\frac{e^{-tx}}{1 + x}\right] \right| &= \left| \frac{-xe^{-tx}}{1 + x} \right|\\
>     &= \frac{xe^{-tx}}{1 + x}.
> \end{align*}
>
> Consider the function
>
> \begin{align*}
>     g(x) := \frac{xe^{-tx}}{1 + x} + \frac{1}{e^x}.
> \end{align*}
>
> Certainly we have
>
> \begin{align*}
>     \frac{xe^{-tx}}{1 + x} \leq \frac{xe^{-tx}}{1 + x} + \frac{1}{e^x}
> \end{align*}
>
> for all $x \in [0, \infty)$ and $a \leq t \leq b$. Therefore it remains to show that
>
> \begin{align*}
>     \int_{[0, \infty)} \frac{xe^{-tx}}{1 + x} + \frac{1}{e^x} \, d\mu_{\mathcal{L}} < \infty.
> \end{align*}

**Discussion and Questions:**

What I really want to do is split the last integral into two integrals and say that they are both obviously finite, therefore I'm done. **How can I justify this?**

That's my main concern. Of course, if I chose the wrong function $g$ for the proof (or worse, I'm applying the wrong theorem in the first place) then I have bigger problems.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're using that theorem, $g$ cannot depend on $t$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring Thanks. That leaves me a bit lost as to which function $g$ to pick, though. Because when $t$ is very small I'm looking at something approaching $x/(1+x)$.

Comment: This makes me wonder if I'm trying to apply the wrong theorem. But I don't see any obvious alternative candidates.

Comment: @Novice what about focusing on $t \in(\varepsilon,\infty)$? In that case, $g(x)=e^{-\varepsilon x}$ should work as the 'integrable majorant' for the derivative. Also, $\varepsilon$ can be arbitrarily small.

Comment: @Snoop Hi, I'm not sure if you saw my edit, but basically I tried to pick appropriate functions $g$ so that $F(t)$ is differentiable on closed intervals that cover $(0, \infty)$. I needed those functions $g$ to be at least as big a certain function on the given closed interval, and to have finite Lebesgue integral over the whole space. I *think* I've accomplished that now. I'm at the limit of my ability here so I can't evaluate whether your suggestion would work. Thanks though.